# Excel Sort by 2nd character in alphanumeric string

Tags: regex, sorting, excel, excel-formula, vba

I have a column in an Excel spreadsheet that contains the following:

```
### - 3-digit number
#### - 4-digit number
A### - character with 3-digits
#A## - digit followed by character then 2 more digits
```

There may also be superfluous characters to the right of these strings.

I would like to sort the entire spreadsheet by this column in the following order (ascending or descending):

the first three types of strings alphabetically as expected (NOT ASCII-Betically!)
Then the #A## by the character first, then by the first digit.

```
Example:
000...999, 0000...9999, A000...Z999, 0A00...9A99, 0B00...9B99...9Z99
```

I feel there is a very simple solution using a regular expression or macro but my VBa and RegExp are pretty rusty (a friend asked me for this but I' m more of a C-guy these days). I have read some solutions which involve splitting the data into additional columns which I would be fine with.

I would settle for a link to a good guide. Eternal thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to sort by second character regardless of the content ahead and behind, then regex `^.(.)` represents second character match...

Comment: I'll try it and update, I'd still need to then sub-sort by the first character for that type.